# Firebase Firestone Random Document from Database

Tags: android, random, document

Here is my Firebase FireStone Database Structure:

**MainPosts**

- 7YBc5LhUwU2wQB4ZybOl
- IcInT5YEPKL2TVSAADP2
- tiUCi5IUuuCA2BT5Ldda

This is my Code:

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("MainPosts").addSnapshotListener(SingleVideoActivity.this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

            for (DocumentChange doc : documentSnapshots.getDocumentChanges()) {
                if (doc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                    String blogPostId = doc.getDocument().getId();

                    BlogPost blogPost = doc.getDocument().toObject(BlogPost.class).withId(blogPostId);

                    blog_list.add(blogPost);
                    blogListRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

What i want to do to get random document like from this three :-

- 7YBc5LhUwU2wQB4ZybOl
- IcInT5YEPKL2TVSAADP2
- tiUCi5IUuuCA2BT5Ldda

Comment: it's not so easy to do this.  I'd use a Cloud Function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it by save documents with a specific name. Upload a file this way:

```
StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
//find your way to keep thees values 
string documentName = "1";//if it is the first file, if the file is second post the value should be 2
string documentExtention = ".doc"; 

storageRef.child("MainPosts/"+ documentName + documentExtention);
```

When you have to download:
Get a random:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int lastUploadedFileNumber = 50; // if you have 50 files in FirebasStore
int  randomNumber = rand.nextInt(lastUploadedFileNumber) + 1;
```

Then download the random file in local file:

```
StorageReference downloadRef = storageRef.child("MainPosts/"+ randomNumber.toString() + documentExtention);

File localFile = File.createTempFile("radomFileName", documentExtention);

downloadRef .getFile(localFile).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(FileDownloadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        // Local temp file has been created
        showFile(localFile); //implement a way to show the file
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! :) that can work! thanks you so much!

Comment: Can you Please solve my one more quest?

i had a category in the document that i mention above is there is a way to display tha category data only. If categoty is SAD the show only that document